# Smooth $S^3$-action

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups

Does $S^4$ admit a smooth $S^3$-action?

If there is such an action, I think it would have to be non-free: if it were free, then the quotient manifold theorem gives that $S^4\to Q:=S^4/S^3$ is an submersion. By the long exact sequence of homotopy groups, $Q$ would be a compact simply connected 1-manifold, i.e. the interval $[0,1]$. But $[0,1]$ is contractible, so an $S^3$ bundle over $[0,1]$ would have to be trivial. But $S^4\neq S^3\times [0,1]$, so the action cannot be free.

Now $S^4$ is "almost" $S^3\times [0,1]$ in the sense that $S^4$ is the quotient of $S^3\times [0,1]$ with the sets $S^3\times \{0\}$ and $S^3\times \{1\}$ collapsed to a point.

Pick a nontrivial smooth self-action of $S^3$ on itself (maybe conjugation?). Write coordinates on $S^4$ locally as $(h,t)$ where $h\in S^3$ and $t\in [0,1]$. Define $f:S^3\times S^4\to S^4$ by $$(g,(h,t))\mapsto (ghg^{-1},t).$$

This action is trivial for $t=0,1$, so it is not free. I'm not sure if it is smooth. Does this example work?

More generally, suppose $S^3\to M\to N$ is a smooth $S^3$-bundle with $M$ compact. Does $M$ then necessarily admit a nontrivial smooth $S^3$-action?

Comment: Indeed, the antipodal map from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the only free action on an even dimensional sphere, so it is VERY far from being free.  I think Borsuk Theorem pulled back from one sphere onto the other shows that only trivial actions are possible.

Comment: The easiest way to think of your $S^4$ action is as follows. $S^3$ is the group of unit quaternions, and it acts by multiplication on the vector space $\Bbb H$. The one-point compactification $S^{\Bbb H}$ is a 4-dimensional smooth manifold with $S^3$ action fixing $0$ and $\infty$, and acting freely on the complement. You could also imagine an action via the double cover $S^3 \to SO(3)$ acting on $\Bbb R^3 \oplus \Bbb R$ (trivially on the second coordinate), and passing to the one-point compactification. I think every $S^3$ action on $S^4$ is probably conjugate to one of these, or trivial.

Comment: Note that there is a diffeomorphism $S^V \cong S(V \oplus \Bbb R)$, the latter meaning unit sphere, taking the actions arising as "compactifications of linear actions on $V$" to "restrictions of linear actions on $V \oplus \Bbb R$". The latter might be easier to picture.

Comment: I missed one: $SO(3)$ has an irreducible 5-dimensional representation we can restrict to the 4-sphere. It has two orbits of type $\Bbb{RP}^2$, and every other orbit is $SO(3)/V_4$, where $V_4$ is the subgroup of diagonal matrices. It is indeed true that every action is conjugate to one of these.